# XMLParser encounter invalid tags

Tags: swift, xml

I'm writing an RSS reader app using Swift. I use the built-in class `XMLParser` to do the parsing job.

The `XMLParser` would stop when encounter some strange tags, for instance, `<figure>`(This tag is matched by end tag `</figure>`). The error code is 76(`tagNameMismatchError`).

I extract the part causing the `tagNameMismatchError` from xml:

```
<figure tabindex="0" draggable="false" class="ss-img-wrapper" contenteditable="false"><img src="https://cdn.sspai.com/2019/08/19/34d2340bbf2cbc3b08ffe4fe1594168d.png" alt=""><figcaption class="ss-image-caption">图 / iHelpBR</figcaption></figure>
```

**Why this error(`tagNameMismatchError`)? It is `<figure>` an invalid tag or something else?**

Besides, I can't predict what possible tags could come from possible feeds.

Comment: You should add your xml example. It is difficult to provide a solution without more info.

Comment: @DCTID Hi, I extracted the part causing the error from xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `img` tag, which is not terminated. This is not valid XML. HTML is more lax regarding closing tags than XML is. Insert a `</img>` or change the `img` tag to be `<img src=... />` and it will work.

If you ever need to confirm that the content is valid XML, you can also save it to a file and then use the command line `xmllint` which will report (emphasis added):

> parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: **img** line 1 and **figure**

Bottom line, you’ll need to fix the XML, or use a HTML parser (such as [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple)) instead.